# Output results from Linux command into a table with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, linux, html-table

I'm mid way through clobbering together a captive portal to run on a Raspberry Pi and have the basics working, but I'm now stumbling whilst creating some administration pages.

What I am essentially trying to do is create a table in HTML/PHP so that I have the ability to "kick" users from the service. I have a script already in place that does this, but I'm struggling to echo the results of an exec statement into a table.

This is how far I've managed to get:

```
<?php
    $mac = array();
    exec( "sudo iptables -L -t mangle | grep MAC | cut -d' ' -f37", $mac );
    $ip = array();
    exec( "sudo arp -i eth1 -a | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d '()'", $ip );
?>
<style>
    table, tr, td, th
    {
        font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:11px;">
            Currently connected:<br><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>MAC</th>
                    <th>IP</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo implode("<br />", $mac); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo implode("<br />", $ip); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This outputs to a table, but not into a row per IP. I'd like this to be a new row so that I can then add a third column to contain something like

```
echo "<td><a href='/scripts/block.php?IP=" . $row['IP'] . "'>Block</a></td>";
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could should post a few lines of output from your iptables & arp command chains?

Comment: The output of the iptables after the grep and cut in PHP shows as:
00:15:5D:10:25:11 00:15:5D:10:25:02
With the implode break this puts them onto separate lines, but I would like them to go to separate rows within the table.
The output of the arp command with the cut and tr is similar, just two IP addresses inline separated by a space rather than in new rows, with the implode putting them onto different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working with the following:

```
<?php
    $mac = array();
    exec( "sudo iptables -L -t mangle | grep MAC | cut -d' ' -f37", $mac );
    $ip = array();
    exec( "sudo arp -i eth1 -a | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d '()'", $ip );
?>

<style>
    table, tr, td, th
    {
        font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>MAC</th>
                <th>IP</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach(array_combine($ip, $mac) as $ipaddress => $macaddress){
    echo "<tr><td>".$ipaddress."</td><td>".$macaddress."</td></tr>";
}
?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which now outputs as:

```
<style>
    table, tr, td, th
    {
        font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>MAC</th>
                <th>IP</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>10.0.128.107</td><td>00:15:5D:10:25:11</td></tr><tr><td>10.0.128.106</td><td>00:15:5D:10:25:02</td></tr>        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the assistance!